# python / urwid ListBox object not callable

Tags: python, urwid

I've discovered urwid recently and started to play around with it. I've seen a Menu like tutorial example (which works!) and I've tried to modify the code a bit so I can get back and forth in the menu for starters - without doing anything else.

However I got stuck - and Im at a loss on why its happening.

Running this code:

```
    import urwid

    choices = u'Tank_1 Tank_2 Tank_3 Solarkreis Exit'.split()

    def menu(title, choices):
        body = [urwid.Text(title), urwid.Divider()]
        for c in choices:
            button = urwid.Button(c)
            if c == "Exit":
                urwid.connect_signal(button, 'click', exit_program)
            else:
                urwid.connect_signal(button, 'click', item_chosen, c)
            body.append(urwid.AttrMap(button, None, focus_map='reversed'))


        return urwid.ListBox(urwid.SimpleFocusListWalker(body))

    def item_chosen(button, choice):
        response = urwid.Text([u'Uebersicht ', choice, u'\n'])
        done = urwid.Button(u'Ok')
        urwid.connect_signal(done, 'click', menu(u'Menu', choices))
        main.original_widget = urwid.Filler(urwid.Pile([response,
            urwid.AttrMap(done, None, focus_map='reversed')]))

    def exit_program(button):
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()

    main = urwid.Padding(menu(u'Menu', choices), left=2, right=2)
    top = urwid.Overlay(main, urwid.SolidFill(u'\N{MEDIUM SHADE}'),
        align='center', width=('relative', 60),
        valign='middle', height=('relative', 60),
        min_width=20, min_height=9)
    urwid.MainLoop(top, palette=[('reversed', 'standout', '')]).run()
```

Running it I get

```
TypeError: 'ListBox' object is not callable
```

And I done quite understand how and why.. Help is much appreciated!

Edit: Forgot to add, the error pops up when I try to go back from the sub - menu to the original menu.

Answer (score 0):

line 22, the third parameter is a ListBox object not a callable function.
    urwid.connect_signal(done, 'click', menu(u'Menu', choices))